# Can I install a hardwood floor in the kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, installation, hardwood-floor

I don't know if I can install a hardwood floor in my kitchen. 
What would you recommend ?

Thank you so much

Camille

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is far too broad a question for our format. If you have a specific query you can edit your question to show it.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. But it's a bad idea, because kitchens are wet and have people walking around in them all the time. A wood floor will scratch and wear quickly, and be exposed to conditions that can encourage warping, rot, or mold.

So ideally you want something durable and not affected by water, and probably something that's attractive, too. That pretty much leaves tile, which, incidentally enough, is why most kitchens are tiled nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can install a hardwood floor in your kitchen, you just have to wipe up any spillages and water quickly and also look at getting the correct maintenance carried out in that area more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a hardwood floor in the kitchen, but the high traffic and damage caused by dropped foods make vinyl a better choice because vinyl is water resistant and it is physically softer, resulting in fewer broken dishes, and it is much less expensive and easier to replace or cover than refinishing a hardwood floor.

But, vinyl and linoleum don't have the sophisticated look of hardwood... by sophisticated, of course, I mean expensive.